# The Bowery King's Status in John Wick

Tags: plot-explanation, character, john-wick

In the John Wick Series, the high table is presented as the ultimate point of underworld decision and command center. From the John Wick [Fandom Page](https://johnwick.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bowery_King):

> Soon after, he took control of The Soup Kitchen, a homeless shelter, where he created an underground empire. Recruiting a large number of beggars, vagrants, and panhandlers to act as his eyes and ears in the city, and training pigeons to act as messengers, he established a large intelligence and data network across New York, without using the internet or phones, thus remaining anonymous and untraceable. He then **informally** became an **adjutant to The High Table**, bound under their rules but operating independently.

Does it say that The Bowery King is or was part of the High table, since his empire (The Soup Kitchen) functions with the gold coin as accepted currency? Does Winston, the keeper ever have any connection with him (Bowery King)? Who funds his kitchen, or what was his source of income in running the kitchen other than the gold?

Answer (score 2):

They don't really go into his operating costs or how he makes a living in the movies.  However, we do know that underneath the Soup Kitchen there are a series of tunnels and escape passages guarded by his men, and it's logical to believe that he's paid for the use of them.  We also know he gave Wick a handgun in Wick 2, and charged him $1M for each of the 7 bullets.

Is he a part of The High Table? You answered your own question. He's an adjutant and operates independently of The High Table.